# ListViewByQuery doesn't show correct columns when GroupBy specified

Tags: sharepoint, listview, sharepoint-2010

I am using Sharepoint 2010, and wrote an application page in C#/VS2010.  I am using ListViewByQuery to display a list.  All is well, until I add the GroupBy tag to group the list.  When this is added, for some reason the columns I've chosen with query.ViewFields are ignored, and instead three other columns are displayed, both when collapsed and when expanded.  Code is here:

```
            //this section demonstrates how to display a list in an SP Application Page project:
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            myListQuery.List = web.Lists["Links"];
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery(myListQuery.List.DefaultView);
            //note: there seems to be bug somewhere... when the list is grouped by (folders), you
            //      don't see the fields you request - just three basic fields.  It seems to ignore the ViewFields
            //      that you specified, unless you don't group.  Weird.
            query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"URLwMenu\" /><FieldRef Name=\"List\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Category\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Author\" />";
            query.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\"List\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">Projects</Value></Contains></Where>";
            //if this next line is commented out, all the correct columns are shown
            query.Query += "<GroupBy Collapse=\"FALSE\" GroupLimit=\"100\"><FieldRef Name=\"Category\"></GroupBy>";
            myListQuery.DisableFilter = false;
            myListQuery.DisableSort = false;
            myListQuery.Query = query;
        }
```

The columns that **are** shown, in this example, are Type, Edit, URL, and Notes.  If anyone has any clues, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing the / in the closing tag of the FieldRef in the GroupBy clause:

```
<FieldRef Name=\"Category\">
```

Comment: Rawbert, you ROCK!  Thanks so much, that was it.  Changed the fieldref part to <FieldRef Name=\"Category\" />